Signal Protocol - PreKeys/SignedPreKeys purpose
I don't really understand purpose of signedprekeys, I see signal protocol like this:
Alice: pub, priv keys, prekey that converts to signedprekey
Bob: pub, priv keys, prekey that converts to signedprekey
And to encrypt message you need not only recipent public key, you need also a signedprekey for some reason.
I heard that signedprekey regenerates for every message/session. If it's true, it explain presignedkeys purpose, but dont explain reason of additional encryption. Because presignedkeys and public key store at the same place, so if hacker will collect pub key, he will collect all presignedkeys too.
